# Como deshabilitar un input después de enviar datos de un formulario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, html5

quisiera saber como puedo deshabilitar campos de texto al momento de enviar datos de un formulario, es decir, cuando hago click en el botón, estos se puedan deshabilitar automáticamente.

He intentado realizarlo con javascript por medio de este método simple:

```
let titulo = document.getElementById("titulo");
if(titulo){
        titulo.disabled = true;
    }else{
        titulo.disabled = false;
    }

<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo"
    placeholder="" value="{{$user->titulo}}">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
 <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-8" id="div_confirmacion2">
   <button type="submit"
    class="btn indigo white-text text-bold float-right"
    id="update_datos_comple">
    Guardar cambios
    </button>
  </div>
```

Y al momento de enviar los datos el campo se deshabilita (ya que dicho envío lo tengo con un ajax para evitar el refresh de la página). Pero al momento de recargar la pagina por mi cuenta, el formulario no toma el "bloqueo" que si se hizo anteriormente, es decir, el campo vuelve a habilitarse, ¿Como lo puedo dejar bloqueado o deshabilitado permanentemente luego de enviar el dato que se agregó en el input?

Comment: una cookie ( q la pueden borrar ) o guardalo en la sesion y lo lees al renderizar el form nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar agregando la siguiente condición `@if ($user->titulo) disabled="" @endif`

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" 
               class="form-control" 
               id="titulo" 
               value="{{ $user->titulo }}" 
               @if ($user->titulo) disabled="" @endif
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas sencilla de comprender es esta.
Agregas un method capturando el ID de nuestros elemento que seran bloqueados y posteriormente agregaras el cambio mediante objects. Agregas el atributo de disabled as true y tu elemento ya no podra ser editado.
Puedes dejar el input fuera del ajax y agregar el codigo durante el evento de "guardar" ya puede variar la solucion dependiendo de como estes mas comodo. Espero y ter sirva.

```js
/**
 * 
 * @name fnDisableButton
 * @summary El TextBox se desbilitara despues de dar click a "Guardar Cambios"
 * @author Rak
 * @param strID
 * @returns N/A
 */

function fnDisableButton(strID) {
  document.getElementById(strID).setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <!-- Agregando ID para proceder a la identificacion del elemento -->
    <input id="txtBox" type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" placeholder="" value="Your Value">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-8" id="div_confirmacion2">
  <!-- Agregando Method On click para Blockear el elemento -->
    <button type="submit" onclick="fnDisableButton('txtBox');" class="btn indigo white-text text-bold float-right" id="update_datos_comple">
    Guardar cambios
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Esto no responderia a la pregunta, ya que el OP quiere que el boton se mantenga deshabilidato aun cuando se recarga la pagina

Comment: Es por eso que recomiendo que después de que se realice el request y posterior al refresh agrege la funcion para setear el elemento como "disabled" esta funcion se dispara siempre y cuando el usuario de click en button.